# Turn off "ask to save" for Windows Notepad

Tags: windows, notepad

Is there a way to disable the "Do you want to save changes" dialog for Notepad on Windows 10?

I mainly use it as a temporary editor (to monitor the clipboard or to write text for dynamically managed web content, lest I accidentally cancel an action, etc.)

And **IF** I want to save something, I'm gonna save it.
I really don't need that feature with Notepad ("Serious" work I do in Notepad++)

If not, I'll just make my own Notepad in Visual Studio, where I'll include the option of making this choice - but it would be nice if I didn't have to :)

Comment: Why don't you use Notepad++ for everything then? It auto-caches temporary buffers when you close the app, for instance, with the Preferences/Backup/Remember current session option.

Comment: No big reason, i just like to keep the two separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  Get busy with Visual Studio.

No settings in the application and looking at the registry reveals only settings for word wrap, visibility of status bar, and window position.